# How to run batch query in excel and get result into worksheet?

Tags: excel, batch-file

At the moment I'm using batch file which contains this query:

```
dir "\\directory\folder\example" > file.xls /b /o
```

Once I execute it I receive .xls file which is used as data source in workbook.

Is it possible to run such a query once I open workbook and get data into specified worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you can use Power Query to load an Excel file as a data source, or list out all files in a folder and use these files subsequently as data sources.

Power Query is a free download from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and is built into Excel 2016 as "Get & Transform" in the Data ribbon.

Queries built with this technique can be refreshed from inside the Excel workbook.

Edit: If you work with an older version of Excel, you may need to resort to VBA to get a list of files into Excel. I have written a routine a while back and describe it in detail in "[List all files in folder to Excel](http://www.teylyn.com/list-all-files-in-folder-to-excel/)" 
. It may do too much for your taste, but you can always throw things out. The link contains a sample file with all the code.

Comment: Thank you for a fast response. This solution works if at least IE9 is installed, but unfortunately, I can't use it so I can't install Power Query. I need another way to get files list.

Comment: I added a link to a VBA based solution.

Comment: Thank you once again, as I see it really does much more than I need. It still not what I'm looking for. I just need the simplest way to refresh the list with the file names once I open a document.

This vba solution almost fits for me: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/627-excel-list-files.html

Is it possible to get files list without poping up dialog boxes and selecting folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named formula too.

- Put the path and filefilter in cell A1, e.g.:
  c:\Users\YourName\Documents\*.xls*
- Press control F3 and click "New"
- Name it "ListOfFiles" (without the quotes)
- In the refersto box, enter this:

=FILES($A$1)

- Press OK and close Name Manager
- In cell B1 enter:

=INDEX(ListOfFiles,ROW())

- Drag down B1 until you get #REF!